# $\operatorname{Pr}(A \cap B | C)=\operatorname{Pr}(A | C) \cdot \operatorname{Pr}(B | C)$

Tags: probability

I know this is similar to the theorem for Independence , but what is this one called? conditional Independence ?

Comment: yes it is conditional independence https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_independence

Comment: Instead of `\operatorname{Pr}` you can just use `\Pr` $\Pr$